# Mac cannot access an executable file form one folder

Tags: bash, phantomjs, osx-yosemite

I am trying to use phantomJs from 2 different folders, but the KoGoal cannot find it, even though they're both looking in the same folder for it.

From Maestro folder:

```
Geoffreys-MacBook-Pro:maestro gkburdett$ which phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Geoffreys-MacBook-Pro:maestro gkburdett$ phantomjs --version
1.9.8
```

From KoGoal Folder:

```
Geoffreys-MacBook-Pro:kogoal gkburdett$ which phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Geoffreys-MacBook-Pro:kogoal gkburdett$ phantomjs --version
-bash: /bin/phantomjs: No such file or directory
```

OS10.10.2

I don't even know what to look for here.

Comment: did u switch users? or new shell.  that seems to make no sense do a ls -lsa /usr/local/bin

Comment: I just reset the computer...works every time!